# How to add today's date in Marp markdown

Tags: marp, marpit

all

I am looking for a simple way to add today's date in my marp markdown. Something like

```markdown
{{ date }}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using the `Date()` function in JS. This could then be customised to display exactly what you wanted (date, time, specific date format etc.)

With this method though, if viewing as a HTML slide deck then the datetime will change each time the page is loaded.

If you wanted to insert a static time (e.g. file save date etc), perhaps the easiest way would be to just do a regex replace on a certain phrase eg. {{ date }} as above, before you get Marp to convert the document.

```
---
marp: true
---

Refresh to see changes...

<p id="date1"></p>
<p id="date2"></p>
<p id="date3"></p>

<script>
    const now = new Date()
    document.getElementById("date1").innerHTML = now;
    document.getElementById("date2").innerHTML = now.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
    document.getElementById("date3").innerHTML = now.toLocaleDateString("en-US", {weekday: 'long'});
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work.